# Orthographic projection of point $[0, 0, 0]$

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the easiest way to calculate orthographic projection of point $[0, 0, 0]$ on a plane given by formula $x - y + z = 1$?

Comment: What do you mean by 'orthographic projection'? Paallel to the axes?

Comment: @copper.hat According to wikipedia it means orthogonal projection.

Comment: In technical drawing it means projections onto the $xy,yz,zx$ planes.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Consider the line perpendicular to the plane through the point. Get the intersection of the line and the plane and you have the projection.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** given a plane $\pi: \ ax+by+cz = d$, the vector ${\bf n} = (a,b,c)$ is normal to the plane. What is $\bf n$ in your case? Take the line $$L: \ {\bf X}(t) = (0,0,0) + t{\bf n}, \quad t \in \Bbb R.$$
Find $t_0$ such that ${\bf X}(t_0)$ satisfies the equation of your plane. Then ${\bf X}(t_0)$ is the point you're looking for.